# Google+ API Application Readiness

Tags: android, google-plus

Hi I am in the process of trying to make a google+ app for the Android, Could some explain and tell me what this quote means exactly, "**The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data**.

I want to make a app similiar to the way other developer are making their own apps similiar to facebook and twitter,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the API currently only allows to access data that is **public**, and you can only **read** data with it *(i.e. you cannot do any "write" operation)*

On the opposite, twitter's API allows one to access **private** data *(like direct messages)*, and to do some **write**-operations, like post a new tweet.

Comment: Oh I see, so I guess that may not be an option because I want to be able to post within the stream api. (ie some make a post then I reply to it, or post a status message).